# "It would not do to confuse the nurses with the patients"

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

From http://www.debate.org/debates/School-uniforms-ought-to-be-worn-in-primary-and-secondary-schools./1/:

> For many of these, the reason for wearing a uniform is clear: so that they are easily recognizable. In a hospital, for example, **it would not do** to confuse the nurses with the patients.

What did the author mean by "it would not do"? Can anyone parse this sentence please? Or is it a typo?

Comment: The "it would not do" part is fine -- but the "confuse the nurses with the patients" part is ambiguous.

Comment: @Jerry: I found the phrase perfectly clear. Why is it ambiguous?

Comment: @MrHen: It could refer to either a nurse being confused *for* a patient, or a nurse being confused *by* a patient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sentence is fine as it stands: "it would not do" means something like "it would not be a good thing to have happen" here.

Comment: Does this phrase sound oral or just fine in written English?

Comment: @trVoldemort: It is fine in written English.

Comment: It's fallen out of common usage in spoken English and would sound affected unless you roll like that.

Answer (score 10):

It means *it would be wrong* or *it would be undesirable*

Answer (score 8):

In this usage, "it would not do" is perfectly valid and indicates that the following expression is undesirable, as in "this will not do at all".

Answer (score 6):

It is an idiom, meaning "it would not be appropriate".

OED, s.v. "do", v; 20.a. "To ‘work’, ‘act’, operate, or turn out (in some way); to do what is wanted; to succeed, answer, or serve; to be fitting or appropriate; to suffice. that will do (that'll do): that is sufficient."

Comment: (+1) I'd add that this phrase does sound rather dated now in *spoken* English. It sounds like the vocabulary of a character in an Agatha Christie or PG Wodehouse country house novel, rather than contemporary British English. "Come come, old chap, it simply would not do!"

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you're familiar with that use of "do", you just haven't thought about it before. Consider the following:

- Person 1: Have you got a pencil?
- Person 2: No, I got a felt-fit pen, though.
- Person 1: That will do.

Comment: "It would not do" generally goes further than the opposite of "that will do" and means something would be inappropriate, disrespectful or improper.